# Preventing duplicate key errors in EF-Core InMemory provider through locking

Tags: c#, locking, entity-framework-core

I have a rest service on Azure AD that calls other rest services. They use AzureAd authentication and `AuthContext` with a custom TokenCache that stores each users tokens in an **InMemory** EF Core database. Sometimes I'd get exceptions in `AfterAccessNotification` when I'd call SaveChanges().

```
var cache = context.TokenCacheEntries.Find(userObjectId) ?? context.TokenCacheEntries
                                .Add(new TokenCacheEntry { userObjId = userObjectId }).Entity;
                cache.LastWrite = DateTime.Now;
                cache.cacheBits = Serialize();

                // update the DB and the lastwrite                
                context.SaveChanges();
                HasStateChanged = false;
```

A possible cause of this is I have to initialize this context in the Singleton scope because I use it via AuthContext in [my JwtBearerEvents.OnTokenValidated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.ontokenvalidated?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerEvents_OnTokenValidated) method.

I solved the problem with a lock:

```
    private static object saveLock = new object();

    /// <remarks>
    /// Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
    /// If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
    /// </remarks>>
    private void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {

        if (HasStateChanged)
        {
            // SaveChanges() threw an exception that a key already existed once so lets hope this lock fixes that.
            lock (saveLock)
            {
                // retrieve last write from the DB
                var cache = context.TokenCacheEntries.Find(userObjectId) ?? context.TokenCacheEntries
                                .Add(new TokenCacheEntry { userObjId = userObjectId }).Entity;
                cache.LastWrite = DateTime.Now;
                cache.cacheBits = Serialize();

                // update the DB and the lastwrite                
                context.SaveChanges();
                HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: A `lock` works pretty well here, assuming you don't have multiple users with a need to call to it at once. You can also catch the exception being thrown and recheck to see if there's a valid token in the cache.

Answer (score 7):

A `lock` works here, and it's functional, but it does come with some drawbacks in this case.

If you and I both submit the request at the same time, one of them will be delayed even though there wasn't actually a reason. Now you've introduced a potentially hazardous situation, what happens if a lot of *distinct* persons submit requests at once?

The best option here, is to block *only those who violated the key sanity*. The easiest way to do this is *actually* to `catch` the appropriate exception.

There's a nice question about this on Stack Overflow, which I would like to borrow some information from: [Duplicate key exception from Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967140/duplicate-key-exception-from-entity-framework)

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896322/4564272) that looks promising, which looks like:

```
try
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    SqlException innerException = ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException;
    if (innerException != null && (innerException.Number == 2627 || innerException.Number == 2601))
    {
        //your handling stuff
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Based on the research I could suss-out in a short bit, this looks like it's appropriate for EF-Core, whereas the accepted answer looks more like EF on standard. I can't test it, so I leave it to you, but I would go more towards *this* route than a shared lock.

Of course, it's up to you, but I wouldn't even try to re-save the `LastWrite` on a duplicate key violation, because we *know* it's going to be **right now**, so why do the extra work? I'd just `catch` and swallow in this case, with a clear comment as to why:

```
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    SqlException innerException = ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException;
    if (innerException != null && (innerException.Number == 2627 || innerException.Number == 2601))
    {
        // Swallow the exception, as the only thing we're updating is the `LastWrite`, which will be the current date/time so there's not point in doing additional queries;
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Depending on the logic, I may also even recommend tracking that further up the stack, and only call to this function *if* it needs updated. (Rather than for every update.)

Comment: Thanks. Another curious thought, what if i had a dictionary of lock objects keyed to the user id and effectively only locked per user? Another part of the problem is I never actually call Acquire TokrnSilent() so I'm always writing new keys. Actually reading from the cache likely makes this a rare occurrence.  And yes it would have to be some sort of cached dictionary of lock objects where the keys expire.

Comment: Oh you can for sure. You'll still lose some performance for each lock but that _should_ prevent the lock from interfering with other sessions. You can always `Dictionary<Token, object>`. You can also use a more sophisticated option like [this other question does](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105523/item-level-locks-for-a-large-number-of-items).

Comment: While this answer solves the OP's issue, it raises a lot of other hell with it.