# Dictionary for locking on unique identifiers without leaking memory

Tags: c#, locking

The following code is greatly inspired on [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105523/item-level-locks-for-a-large-number-of-items) question and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106343/49776) answer. That answer works quite well for a specific case, but I was looking for a solution that:

1. could be used more generic (so I can put this in a base library and never have to think about it anymore).
2. got rid of the `Find()` and replace it with a O1 dictionary lookup. To be honest I doubt if this would have any performance effect, but it was tickling my OCDs.

I've tried to test it with running about 10 threads and superficially it *seems* to work. But as concurrency is hard to test and reason about - am I missing something? Any other obvious upgrades?

```
public class LockDictionary<TKey>
{
    object _RootLock = new object();
    Dictionary<TKey,ItemLock> _KeyToLock = new Dictionary<TKey,ItemLock>();


    public IDisposable Lock(TKey key)
    {
        ItemLock item_lock;

        lock  ( _RootLock )
        {
            item_lock = GetOrCreate(key);
            item_lock._Counter++;
        }

        Monitor.Enter(item_lock);

        return new LockCounter(this, key);
    }


    private ItemLock GetOrCreate(TKey key)
    {
        if ( !_KeyToLock.TryGetValue(key, out var item_lock) )
        {
            item_lock = new ItemLock();
            _KeyToLock.Add( key, item_lock );
        }

        return item_lock;
    }


    private void ReleaseLock(TKey key)
    {
        lock (_RootLock)
        {
            var item_lock = _KeyToLock[key];
            item_lock._Counter--;

            if ( item_lock._Counter == 0 )
                _KeyToLock.Remove(key);

            Monitor.Exit(item_lock);
        }
    }


    private class ItemLock
    {
        public object   _ItemLock   = new object();
        public int      _Counter    = 0;
    }


    private class LockCounter : IDisposable
    {
        LockDictionary<TKey> _Parent;
        TKey _Key;


        public LockCounter(LockDictionary<TKey> parent, TKey key)
        {
            _Parent     = parent;
            _Key        = key;
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            _Parent.ReleaseLock(_Key);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

To clarify; I'm looking for an implementation for the following:

```
// minimal definition boilerplate
// possibility of using other types as key, like string, long or a struct
static LockDictionary<int> _LockDictionary = new LockDictionary<int>();

// minimal boilerplate for having a separate lock per "groupId"
using ( _LockDictionary.Lock(groupId) )
{
     // can only be run once concurrently per unique groupId
}
```

Comment: Why you're not locking `Monitor.Enter(item_lock)` with your `_RootLock` but locking `Monitor.Exit(item_lock);`? Seems a bit inconsistent to me

Comment: Good point - I guess I can move the `Monitor.Exit` outside the `_RootLock`.

Comment: If it fits your needs I'd rewrite this to use a `ConditionalWeakTable`, it's probably faster, slimmer and already well tested. Also note that if `Lock()` fails anywhere you might have orphans in your dictionary (and acquired but unreleased locks and/or inconsistencies between `_Counter` and calls to `Monitor.Enter()`). In short...hmmm...instead of trying to have a complex locking mechanism which should be extremely well reviewed (and with good chances to take it wrong), what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @AdrianoRepetti, I've updated the question with the "interface" I'd like to fill. I'm not familiar with `ConditionalWeakTable` but if that makes it easy to be wrapped that would be preferred of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ItemLock._ItemLock is not used anywhere. Also, as a side note, I'm not a fan of using _NamesLikeThis for public items
2. Using a single lock may not be the best idea performance-wise (though heavily scenario-dependent). Consider using CuncurrentDictionary (which of course brings all sorts of new propblems, but this is how concurrency works). Also, you may consider using a ReadWriteLockSlim, it *might* be more performant in some scenarios
3. ReleaseLock is not safe if not matched by a Lock call. Which might happen for example in case of a ThreadAbort. An ugly, but widespread way of dealing with it is placing the critical code to a finally block. This article from the SQL Server people might also be of interest: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/reliability-best-practices

Comment: Hi @vvoton, thanks for your answer. Sorry I broke it with some refactoring during copy pasting - it should now work again.

Comment: What would the fix be for point 3?

Comment: @DirkBoer,the usual (though quite ugly) hack is to put the critical code inside a finally section.  There is a nice article on reliablity from the SQL server team here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/reliability-best-practices

Comment: @Mast, I've updated the answer

Comment: hi @vvotan thanks a lot! Quite interesting! Wouldn't this be applicable to (a lot of) `Dispose()` methods in general though? So do they all have a large `finally` block in there? Isn't it already implied with `Dispose()` that it's quite important that the code should be called? Is that the differentiation? `Dispose()` is important, but `finally` within `Dispose()` is marked as **critical**? It feels a bit *arbitrary*.

Comment: @DirkBoer Usually Dispose does not do anything critical. If it fails, there is always a GC to pick things up. You should only care if you class has some critical resource like a mutex of a file handle and your process absolutely needs to accommodate for this rather low-probability scenario, like for example an SQL server. And there are classes like SafeHandle that do this more or less automagically. Also, .NET core does not support ThreadAborts, which are the most dangerous of the async exceptions so this becomes less of an issue